# Editing multiple SLDs

Tags: geoserver, xml, sld

I have to edit and maintain multiple SLD's. Is there a tool to do bulk edits/ updates?

I have used tools like Atlas SLD to one SLD at a time, and could use XML editing tools to potentially edit multiple but not sure if I can edit multiple SLD's using SLD editors.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by edit multiple SLDs you mean edit them programmatically then you might want to check out [Python-SLD](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sld/). It's a Python library that enables dynamic SLD creation and manipulation. 
Azavea has a [tutorial](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2011/12/introducing-python-sld-and-django-sld/) on how to use Python-SLD.